# Google Analytics request validates correctly, but returns error when sent from CURL

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

I'm sending the following request to Google Analytics:

> http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-72579327-1&cid=61baecac-8f8c-4dce-bf07-a7efa24a4e47&t=transaction&ti=qcY6pvpWGmP9fHyi&tr=10.00&cd1=Acme Racing&cd2=http://www.domain.co.uk/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php/id=314&tid1=12044762460674420322&url=http://www.nitrotek.co.uk&cd3=A1&cd4=Upgrades&cd5=Acme-Tech &cd6={device}&cd7=&cd8=0&cd9=&cd10=&cd11=&cd12=Nitrotek DSA&cd13=g&cd14=50&cd15=1&cd16=85&cd17=12044762460674420322&cd18=&cd19=http://www.domain.co.uk&cd20=61baecac-8f8c-4dce-bf07-a7efa24a4e47&gclid=

When you go to [Google's hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) and validate the request, it comes out valid.

However, when I send the same request through CURL POST, I just get "400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.".

POST is the correct method for this request (though I have tried GET just in case) and the Content-Length header is the length of the sent data (string). Here is the code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $transaction_url,    //the same URL string given above
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'cURL Request'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($transaction_url)    //length of URL string
));
$trans_resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($trans_resp);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `https` instead?

Comment: @jeroen Tried it, same outcome.

Comment: replace blank space by + in your url for eg. Acme Racing to Acme+Racing and so on

Comment: When I do that, the page just keeps loading and then finally fails with a 524 timeout error.

Comment: Can you try to properly urlencode your parameters ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff When I do that, it just returns bool(false).

Comment: When I remove the "post" setting (I now the docs say post, but get works just as well since you send your parameter via the url instead of a post body in any case) and the content length header it starts working, so this seems to be a curl configuration issue rather then a problem with your url.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I just tried the same thing and got the same result. Do you think it could be some sort of encoding setting that I'm missing? What response did you get using GET?